# Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type in Xcode Beta 7, not in beta 6

Tags: xcode6, option-type, xcode6-beta7

This is my code:

```
if let myWindow: UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    window = myWindow
} else {
    window = myWindow2[0] as? UIWindow
}
```

It is throwing this exception at the first line (where it says `if let`):

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

It was working in Beta 6 but I upgraded to beta 7 and now bam. does not work.

What must I do to clear the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Beta 7, `keyWindow` returns a `UIWindow` instead of a `UIWindow!` (it's no longer an optional) so you no longer need the if let.